# How to call Vb6 dll on VC++ without the header

Tags: visual-c++, dll, vb6, dllimport

Is there a way for me to use a dll that come from a VB6 application o VSC++ without the header file?
I have the dll and the .lib and was trying to do the following for loading the dll.

```
    FunctionCalledType calledPTR = NULL;
    hDLL = LoadLibrary(_T("called.dll"));
    if (hDLL == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "DLL called.dll could not be found!";
        return 2;
    }
    calledPTR = (FunctionCalledType)GetProcAddress(hDLL, "FunctionCalled");
    if (NULL != calledPTR)
    {
        std::cout << "Got Function";
        calledPTR("fileA.bz", "fileA.txt");
    }
    else{
        std::cerr << "Didn't got function";
        return 3;
    }
    return 0;
```

The code runs fine but i get a memory access error on

```
        calledPTR("fileA.bz", "fileA.txt");
```

in which FunctionCalledType is defined as follow:

```
 typedef string(CALLBACK* FunctionCalledType)(string, string);
```

And the VB6 code that generated the dll is the following :

```
        Public Function FunctionCalled(src As String, dest As String) As String

           //Some code

        End Function
```

I guess my pointer to the function is on the wrong format, or i am including the dll on the wrong way

Comment: A VB6 DLL is COM based, it does not export anything (aside from RegisterServer)

Comment: This all seems rather implausible. VB6 doesn't support creating unmanaged DLLs. Seems unlikely that this really is a VB6 DLL. And certainly you cannot map C++ `std::string`  to  VB `String`.

Comment: @AlexK. This DLL appears to export a function named `"FunctionCalled"` because, according to asker, `GetProcAddress` succeeds.

Comment: Up to     std::cout << "Got Function"; it works. So if i can't use the dll like this is there another way to do it?

Comment: @FabioCosta I simply don't believe you when you say that this DLL was made by VB6. Because, out of the box, VB6 cannot do what you claim it can do. Furthermore, you appear not to know very much about interop at all, judging from your attempted type mappings. You probably need to recognise your knowledge deficit and rectify it. Sorry.

Comment: The dll was made by a third party and it was informed that it was a VB6 dll, i don't know what they used i just know that it was a dll that had the given signature on there. Yes i don't know a lot about iteropt i was trying to get a function pointer to the DLL and i don't want to learn all about COM and OLE and visual studio ecosystem, i am just trying to get a direction to how to make those two codes speak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the 4 exported functions a VB6.dll has.

```
DllCanUnloadNow
DllGetClassObject
DllRegisterServer
DllUnregisterServer
```

If your code is in a class module you create a object based on VB6's class module then call the function as a method.

It's good you don't want to learn COM. There is almost no chance of this working.

Comment: I used Dll ExportViewer on the DLL and got the 4 above + DllMain and the FunctionCalled that was what i wanted to use. About: " you create a object based on VB6's class module then call the function as a method."  do you have any reference about it? Like a msdn page on the theme?

Comment: @FabioCosta - The relevant MSDN page is [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/194873).

Answer (score -1):

This line is wrong:

```
    calledPTR("fileA.bz", "fileA.txt");
```

Why:

- `String` in VB always `BSTR` and `Byte` always `unsigned char`
- from [document of `BSTR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/automat/bstr):

> The following code is incorrect:
>
> `BSTR MyBstr = L"I am a happy BSTR";`
>
> This code builds (compiles and links) correctly, but it will not
> function properly because the string does not have a length prefix. If
> you use a debugger to examine the memory location of this variable,
> you will not see a four-byte length prefix preceding the data string.
>
> Instead, use the following code:
>
> `BSTR MyBstr = SysAllocString(L"I am a happy BSTR");`
>
> A debugger that examines the memory location of this variable will now
> reveal a length prefix containing the value 34. This is the expected
> value for a 17-byte character string that is represented as a
> wide-string literal through the inclusion of the "L" string prefix.
> The debugger will also show the terminator that appears after the data
> string.
>
> If you pass a wide-string literal as an argument to a COM function
> that is expecting a BSTR, the COM function behaves unexpectedly.

- Notice the definition of `BSTR`:

```
typedef WCHAR OLECHAR;
typedef OLECHAR* BSTR;
typedef BSTR* LPBSTR;
```

- Notice this is COM, not exporting method.

It should be this (even that function doesn't exist):

```
typedef BSTR (CALLBACK* FunctionCalledType)(BSTR, BSTR);
...
    BSTR fileA = SysAllocString(L"fileA.bz");
    BSTR fileB = SysAllocString(L"fileB.bz");
    calledPTR(fileA, fileB);
    SysFreeString(fileA);
    SysFreeString(fileB);
```

This is the list of the functions exported in a example LIB file and that DLL file compiled with it:

```
DllCanUnloadNow
DllGetClassObject
DllRegisterServer
DllUnregisterServer
```

And see comments:

- [C++ 'default argument': cannot convert from 'const wchar_t' to 'BSTR'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74935502/c-default-argument-cannot-convert-from-const-wchar-t-to-bstr#comment132239701_74935502)

> FWIW: [The following code is incorrect: `BSTR MyBstr = L"I am a happy BSTR";`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/automat/bstr)

- [C++ 'default argument': cannot convert from 'const wchar_t' to 'BSTR'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74935502/c-default-argument-cannot-convert-from-const-wchar-t-to-bstr#comment132239525_74935502)

> `wchar_t*` and `BSTR` are the same type. (It's just that `BSTR` needs to be allocated a certain way)