# C++ 'default argument': cannot convert from 'const wchar_t' to 'BSTR'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, windows-xp

1. I start a C++ Project that uses the "Visual Studio 2017 - Windows XP (v141_xp)" Platform Toolset
2. Set Runtime Library to "Multi-Threaded (/MT)"
3. Change "Debug" to "Release"
4. Add `#include "<Wbemidl.h>"` to the source.
5. CTRL F5 (aka Build)

Now, I am aware that platform set is deprecated but, either way, the default x64 build has no issues. However, when I change to "x86" from "x64" (as that's what I want), it then produces numerous errors like the following:

> C++ 'default argument': cannot convert from 'const wchar_t' to 'BSTR'

You might ask what am I trying to do? Maybe some of my code is bad? You should not convert `wchar_t` to `BSTR` as it is not defined what will be the result?

But these aren;t my concerns, here. I didn't add **any** code – just the single header include (I left the "Hello World" part).

I didn't explicitly convert anything as the error is in the Microsoft system headers, not in my Code. I didn't add anything to do with QT nor do I need or want QT so that's not the issue.

I just **for now** want to compile my "Hello World" Program using the `<Wbemidl.h>` header. (Of course, I don't *need* that header to compile it but, if I can compile it without issues, I most likely then can use the library without issues.) I wanted to make this as simple as possible, hence why it just is "Hello World" (a MCVE).

I tried adding the following but without success:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Shlwapi.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "wbemuuid.lib")
```

My best guess is that I didn't install something and or its just deprecated; the funny thing is "2015 Visual Studio (140_xp)" works.

I just want to compile my C++ "Hello World" Program with the Header "<Wbemidl.h>" , Compiled in "x86", Toolset of "Visual Studio 2017 - Windows XP (v141_xp)" and Runtime Library as "Multi-Threaded (/MT)"

My code (MCVE):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Wbemidl.h>    

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

[Microsofts Code ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPISy.png)

Other things I tried:

1. Strict QT strings tags
2. Including other stuff
3. Changing from "Multi-Threaded (/MT)" to "Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)"
4. Tried making 4 Different projects

Comment: What is the line that the error happens on?

Comment: FWIW The type `BSTR` should never be defaulted to a wide character string like `L""` as they are **not** at all the same thing. `BSTR` types carry the length of the string while normal C style wide character strings do not. The header file is incorrect.

Comment: No repro on Visual Studio 2022. Can you double click on one of the error lines in the Visual Studio output and show the offending line of code it's complaining about?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious so how would I fix this , I am aware but once more once again that error is NOT in MY Code thats Microsofts ? Unfortunately I dont have connection with them to let them know :/

Comment: @CaptainObvlious - `wchar_t*` and `BSTR` are the same type. (It's just that BSTR needs to be allocated a certain way).  But the error is complaining about a `const wchar_t[1]` getting converted to non-const BSTR.

Comment: Update to a newer version of the file or edit it and remove the incorrect default argument value.

Comment: @selbie I changed the ask a bit , but I provided images of the code error

Comment: I suspect your compiler is newer that your SDK or vice-versa.  Can you upgrade to latest Visual Studio?

Comment: @selbie Ill try updating everything right now but the Platform Toolset I cant change

Comment: The line in "`WbemDisp.h"` in a Windows 10 SDK is `/* [defaultvalue][in] */ BSTR strObjectPath = (BSTR)L"",` There's a few other places in that file where a wide string literal is cast to a BSTR.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious how would compiling that look like ? would It change size would I have an extra DLL in my release folder because I would have to change their code .

Comment: @RetiredNinja I will attempt this after finishing updating VS thank you

Comment: @selbie No, they point to the same type of character data but they are not the same and BSTR is not just allocated differently. BSTR types have the length prefixed to the character data (4 bytes IIRC) and if that length is not present a lot functions will behave incorrectly.

Comment: FWIW: [The following code is incorrect: BSTR MyBstr = L"I am a happy BSTR";](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/automat/bstr)

Comment: @selbie I could **very quickly** reproduce this in my VS 2022. Just copy/pasted the OP's code, then switched to use the VS 2017 "xp" toolset that the OP clearly mentions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since (IIRC) VS 2019 (and certainly for VS 2022), there is a C++ compiler setting that (by default) forces much stricter adherence to the language standard. That setting ("Conformance Mode") will prevent the conversion (`const w_char[]` to `BSTR`) that is being used in the (older) SDK header files.

This option was already present in VS 2017 but was disabled by default; in VS 2015 (which, you say, works without the errors), the option is simply not present. Thus, when you change the toolset from VS 2022 to VS 2017, you are (unwittingly) enabling that "conformance mode" option.

To disable these errors, you need to turn off conformance mode. In your project settings, go to the "C/C++" … "Language" property page and set "Conformance Mode" to "No":

[image]

There will very likely still be numerous other *warnings* but the system headers will, at least, compile without *errors*.

Note that, when using the newer toolsets, the MSVC compiler uses system header files from a newer SDK; in those headers, the issues have been properly addressed, so conformance mode can be used.